# Launching Firefox into “chromeless” mode from command prompt

Tags: firefox, command-line

Does anyone know if there is a way to launch Firefox (3.*) into "chromeless" mode from command prompt?

The end result I am striving for should look like one of those "chromeless" windows that can be created via the window.open Javascript call. However, I would like the initial Firefox window to be "chromeless" right away. I went through the online documentation of Firefox but failed to find anything relevant.

Does this ring a bell for anyone?

Comment: You mean something like google chrome's "Create Application Shortcut .." thing?

Comment: Yes. But I am sticking with Firefox because it has to work in Windows, Linux and MacOS :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a separate profile in Firefox for your "chromeless mode."  To do that open the profile manager:

```
"\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -ProfileManager
```

Create a new profile called "Chromeless"

- Open the profile and hide the navigation and bookmark toolbars.
- In the Options under Tabs make sure that "Always show the tab bar" is unchecked.
- Install the [Hide Menubar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4762) extension to hide the menu bar

Setup a shortcut to launch your new profile:

```
"\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -no-remote -P Chromeless
```

Comment: Yes, this looks good.  But does it work the same under Linux and Mac OS? I mean, does Firefox have the same commandline interface for all operating systems?

Comment: Yes, it works the same on all operating systems. (Damn 15 char limit.)