# Is there a quick way to remove browser decorations

Tags: firefox, browser, plugins, user-interface

I'm finding that more and more applications use browsers as their user interface and I am caught in a dilemma.

- When browsing I want a browser window to have browser buttons, navigation icons, etc.
- When I'm using the browser for an application like twitter or yammer then I don't need those and having them just reduces the application area.  I would rather save the vertical space and have a very sparse undecorated window.

The problem is it does not seem easy to do this.  My initial thought was to just install two different browsers.  For example use Firefox with all the toolbars and then set IE to show no toolbars.  I think this is ok but I would like a cleaner solution.  Maybe a plugin in Firefox that turns everything off easily or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Prism](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6665) for Firefox or [a Google Chrome application](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95710). I think these might deliver what you're looking for.

Comment: I had no idea Prism existed.  It does EXACTLY what I wanted.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the other browsers, but in Internet Explorer and Firefox you can hit the F11 key and have it go "Full Screen" which removes all the border stuff and gives you more space to do your work.  Then if you need to, you can hit F11 to go back or mouse up to the top to see your menus.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Chrome](http://google.com/chrome) has this feature built in.

For Firefox, you might consider setting up two profiles.  For your applications you  can use the "Apps" profile and then browse under the default profile.  Here are some links for working with Firefox and profiles:

- [Firefox: Using multiple instances with different profiles?](https://superuser.com/questions/41496/firefox-using-multiple-instances-with-different-profiles)
- [Launching Firefox into “chromeless” mode from command prompt](https://superuser.com/questions/55915/launching-firefox-into-chromeless-mode-from-command-prompt)

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm not directly answering the question, but perhaps a compromise between available function and maximum view would be useful?

1. [LittleFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/307)

   > is designed for optimal> screen usage,
   >   leaving lots of room for
   >   browsing. [image]
2. [lifehacker-
   how-to-consolidate-firefox-3s-chrome](http://lifehacker.com/396863/how-to-consolidate-firefox-3s-chrome)
   [image]
3. [lifehacker-
   maximize-firefox-35s-viewing-area-for-your-netbook](http://lifehacker.com/5360263/maximize-firefox-35s-viewing-area-for-your-netbook)
4. [Status Address Bar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/14933)

   > shows the address in the address bar,
   >   so you don't need the status bar