# "chromeless" FF or Opera independent of pre-existing installations

Tags: firefox, installation, browser, opera

How do you install Firefox or Opera in such a way that the installed version is completely independent of other installs of the same browser.

This is Windows specific. I'd like to use my own installer to install a browser which will be run in "chromeless" mode to allow the user to access a web-app.

I want the installed browser to not be disturbed by other installations of the same browser whether they come along later or sooner.

Can someone point me at directions/examples for this ?

*I've seen [Launching Firefox into “chromeless” mode from command prompt](https://superuser.com/questions/55915/launching-firefox-into-chromeless-mode-from-command-prompt) but it doesn't address the issue of installation independence.*

**EDIT**: Having seen Brad Pattons reply I realised I missed something out of this question. I want the browser in question to have auto-updates turned on so that it recieves security patches etc. For this reason I don't think a 'portable app' approach is useful (unless there's something about those I don't know ?)

Comment: This sounds a lot like a SSB - wierdly enough, while they were pretty common at one point, with options like prism, I can't think of any right now

Comment: Interesting you should say that because last night I came across that acroynm (which I'd never heard before) and as you say it seemed to be quite a thing five years ago and not so much now. If others are interested the wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Site-specific_browser gives an overview but there doesn't seem to be much that's cross-platform and "not Chrome" (not willing to involve myself any more with Google than I already am).

Comment: You can just install Firefox in another directory, can't you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for third-party 'portable' installers for Opera. The [standard Opera installer](http://www.opera.com/download/guide/) allows you to install a standalone installation:

[image: Opera stand-alone installation]

This should auto-update just like the regular installation.

Comment: Great answer, thanks very much. It's so long since I installed my 'normal' copy of Opera I was unaware of this option. It certainly allows you invoke a 'Current Version' check so I'm guessing it will indeed do its own one automatically. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Use the versions of those browsers meant to be run on a flash drive (aka the portable versions) but put them on the local drive. They are designed to be self-contained with hooks into the registry, etc.

- [Firefox portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable)
- [Opera USB](http://www.opera-usb.com/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had thought about the approach however I'm not sure I can get auto-updating of the browser to work using those ? I had meant to put that in the question as a need. I've done that now. Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: You can upgrade (see [here](http://portableapps.com/support/firefox_portable#upgrading)) but it will be a manual process. Given the way most installed programs work I'm not sure there is another way to accomplish what you want. Maybe some else will have a different answer.