# As a user, how can I open a site in a popup window without toolbars?

Tags: firefox, browser

Long story short there are webpages and videos I want to display on my secondary monitor while browsing on my main monitor. All of my toolbars and tabs make the browser rather bulky, and I'd like to hide them when I'm just using the window for one webpage.

For example, playing a game on MSN games opens a new popup window, with nothing but the window border and the URL bar:

[image]

This is exactly what I want. However, the URL bar doesn't let me navigate to a different site, which is weird. How can I manually open a blank popup window in Firefox, that I can essentially use as a single-tab trimmed-down browser window?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/55915/launching-firefox-into-chromeless-mode-from-command-prompt possible dupe?

Comment: @Journeyman Geek Not exactly. I don't want to create a new profile or use "chromeless" mode as my default browsing style. I want to be able to open a new slimmed down window alongside my normal browser.

Comment: Create a local html page with a link that has on onclick to window.open() ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open ) and then use that local html page whenever you want less chrome.

Comment: It's not exactly what you're asking for, but perhaps you would enjoy Firefox's [fullscreen mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-make-firefox-and-websites-go-full-screen)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding to Toine42's answer, you can create a JavaScript bookmarklet to open a popup window of the current page:

```
javascript:(function(){window.open(window.location.href,"Google","menubar=no,location=yes")}())
```

Answer (score 4):

A solution is to use the Web Console Menu (which is not user friendly) :

- Open the console menu with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>
- Type in the following JavaScript line `window.open("http://google.fr", "Google", "menubar=no, location=yes")` and validate with `Enter`

Please note that you may have to allow pop-up windows to see the new window.

Additionally, you can tune the window with options in the last argument. A list can be found there : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/open