# How to force a Firefox window to be read-only/non-edtable URL?

Tags: firefox, read-only, popups

I'm receiving via Moodle links to Google Meets for online classes and they usually open on a popup-like window, their URL can't be edited and most of my toolbars on Firefox aren't there, so i can just pin (with an [addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/always-on-top/) an a keyboard shortcut) this window on top of everything and use my screen space optimally.

That's the desired behavior, as it's good to have a small, no-nonsense window for this. However, somewhat often they open up as regular windows, which would be only suited for maximized view, as I have lots of extensions, buttons and so on.

I already have read a bit about why these windows are like this on [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579173/why-is-the-address-bar-not-editable), but only found "why"s, not "how"s.

Anyway, if I have the URL, is there a way to force Firefox in this "popup mode"?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution for a minimal 2nd Firefox window [on this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/942442/as-a-user-how-can-i-open-a-site-in-a-popup-window-without-toolbars?rq=1).

You can either enter this on web console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>):

```
window.open("http://google.com", "Google", "menubar=no, location=yes")
```

Or use this bookmarklet:

```
javascript:(function(){window.open(window.location.href,"","menubar=no,location=yes")}())
```

---

Alternatively, Chrome can even show [websites to look like apps](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/use-chrome-create-windows-10-app-website/).

Drawback of using 2 windows of the same browser: the main Chrome window should always be started first, otherwise existing tabs may be lost when opening an "external" link to another website.

Workaround: use [SessionBuddy](https://sessionbuddy.com/) to restore tabs when lost, it can be configured to show the number of open tabs.

Comment: Thank you, the first part did it! I should note that the Chrome solution wouldn't work for me, since Chrome doesn't have an extension to allow pinning it's window on top of others, as far as I know.

Also, I did a little editing to your answer in order to improve readability and directly include the information you provided.

Comment: Nice to hear that it helped, do you want to set a link to that extension in your question? I am using the Chrome alternative myself because there even the address bar is hidden, it can be pinned to taskbar and has the website's icon in the taskbar.

Comment: Sure, I linked it in the question!